# Firestore Array.map subscribe to collections

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have an array of items, which one property is the reference to a document which has a collection. How could I get an array of items which one property would be the subscription to the document referencered with the docs from the collection?

```
    let myResult = myArray.map(data => {
                               return {...data, 
                               subscription : this.afs.doc(data.refDocument)
                                               .valueChanges().subscribe()}});
```

When try to get the info from `subscription` returns me an Observable ( as I supose), but I would like to get an array of its documents.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `forkJoin` like this [see description in the comment]:

```
const allObs = myArray.map(data => {                            
                        return this.afs.doc(data.refDocument)
                                   .valueChanges()
                                   //I am assuming that this.afs.doc(data.refDocument).valueChanges() observable
                                   //returns docs for the data
                                   .pipe(
                                       //lets take first instance if you expect this to change
                                       //then remove it
                                       take(1),

                                       //lets map the recieved docs to and object which has data + docs
                                       map(doc => {
                                           return {
                                               ...data, docs: doc
                                           };
                                       })
                                   );
                    }
                  );

        forkJoin(allObs).subscribe((result) => {
            //result will be an array of objects; Object -> {...data, docs}
            console.log(result);
            //Do whatever you want to do with result
        });
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Well, first of all, thanks because this works. Sadly, I explained myself bad and what I want is the collection from the doc. we got. The doc has a collection called ('messages') so I would like to subscribe to them. Do you know any way to get this?

Comment: Well, I've checked now and just adding `.collection('messages')` it works. But this returns me the array of data from the collection. Is there any option to subscribe them to reload every time some change is made?

Comment: @Joan As I am not familiar with firebase API so not sure what this `.collection('messages')` returns. But if you expect to get new data every time something changes, then try removing `take(1)` [as i mentioned in the comment]

Comment: Yeah, you are right. But I tried to remove `take(1)` and never enter intro forkJoin method.

Comment: Ah! looks like `this.afs.doc(data.refDocument).valueChanges()` is never complete observable [I am not familiar with firebase :( ] and because of that without `take(1)` will keep observable live because of that `forkJoin` will never emit [as `forkJoin` emits the value when all observable complete].

Comment: You can try `combineLatest(allObs).subscribe()` but I am not sure if it will work.